# Проблема с записью в базу данных

Tags: mysql

При попытке записи данных в базу с кавычками выдает ошибку. Код прилагается. Что надо делать?

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `main` SET rus='$rus_t', eng='$eng_t' WHERE `id` = '1'",$db) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: что за ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Выучите синтаксис

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `main` SET `rus`='".$rus_t."', `eng`='".$eng_t."' WHERE `id` = '1'") or die(mysql_error());
```

2 [[@ArcherGodson](/users/680/archergodson)](/users/680/archergodson) да ошибка скорее всего простая, не может записать в поле значение переменной и ругается :)

Answer (score 0):

Может так:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE main SET rus='".$rus_t."',eng='".$eng_t."' WHERE id = '1'",$db) or die(mysql_error());
```